# Prolog : Evaluating logical expression w/o backtracking with AND/OR op/2?

Tags: prolog, eval, logical-operators

I'm trying to implement logical expressions evaluation w/o backtracking behavior.
After some experimentation I got it working, here goes :

```
:- op(80, xfy, and).
:- op(80, xfy, or).

%check/evaluate logical expressions
check(true) :- !.
check(Cond and Conds) :- !, (check(Cond) , check(Conds)).
check(Cond or  Conds) :- !, (check(Cond) ; check(Conds)), !.  %% <- weird
check(Cond) :- !, call(Cond).



?- check(true and true).
true.

?- check(true and false).
false.

 ?- check(true or false).
 true.

 ?- check(true or (false and true)).
 true.

 ?- check((true or false) and (false and true)).
 false.

 ?- X = 1 , Y = 2 , check((X = 1) and (Y > 1)).
 X = 1,
 Y = 2.
```

So the code works.
My question is why it works, especially the need of two cuts! in  the OR expression.

Does this look like a proper Prolog implementation ?

How would you have done it yourself ?

Comment: Think of cut like it asks prolog to forgot all the points where prolog can backtrack. In or expression if you don't use cut , it will check for both cond operators btw you are using `call/1` in a wrong way, it will always fail. Run the graphical tracer and see how code works with and without cut.

Comment: why would it fail !? it works, call(true) => true

Comment: `call(true)` will look for a predicate in the database , in otherwords it will look for `true` in database but you have no predicate `true` , you have `check(true)`. I think you wanted to use call as `call(check(cond)).` but since nesting is not allowed you have to use `=..`  to first convert it a list then use `call/1`

Comment: ooo this was just demonstration.. check/1 is called normally with logical-expression the call/1 forces evaluation, see the last example

Comment: I dont want to do call(check(Cond)),  I want call(Cond). Cond holds something to be evaluated

Comment: Oops my mistake , did not see the last expression.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim , `true`, when called or queried in Prolog, succeeds by definition.